# A first chance exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-access-2007

I've just moved this code to a new sub and tried to run it and get the exception as said in the tite.

```
Public Sub LoadPanel(TableName As String)

    Debug.Print("LoadPanel:") 'name of module
    PushCallStack("LoadPanel") 'name of module

    Try
        Using dbConnection As New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.SMSA_databaseConnectionString)
            dbConnection.Open()
            Debug.Print("   dbConnection Success")

            Dim sqlcommand As String
            sqlcommand = "SELECT " & TableName & ".[PanelName] FROM  " & TableName & " WHERE (((" & TableName & ".[Owner])=" & CurrentClientID & ")) OR (((" & TableName & ".[Admin1])=" & CurrentClientID & ")) OR (((" & TableName & ".[Admin2])=" & CurrentClientID & ")) OR (((" & TableName & ".[Admin3])=" & CurrentClientID & ")) OR (((" & TableName & ".[Admin4])=" & CurrentClientID & "));"
            Debug.Print("   sqlcommand = " & sqlcommand)

            Dim getSomeData As New OleDbCommand(sqlcommand, dbConnection)
            With getSomeData
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@variableName", "variableValue")
                Debug.Print("   Executing: getSomeData")
            End With
            Debug.Print("   Success: getSomeData")

            Debug.Print("   Try: DataReader")
            Using dataReader As OleDbDataReader = getSomeData.ExecuteReader
                Do While dataReader.Read
                    Dashboard_Client.ComboBox_PanelChoice.Items.Add(dataReader("PanelIP"))
                Loop
            End Using
        End Using

        PopCallStack() 'do not remove
    Catch ex As Exception
        GlobalErrHandler()
    End Try

    Debug.Print("LoadPanel End")
```

From the debug panel:

```
LoadPanel:
dbConnection Success
Executing: getSomeData
Success: getSomeData
Try: DataReader
A first chance exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Data.dll
```

Is there a way to resolve this error or make a work around in order to keep the functionality?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you check with `while` loop instead of `do-while`?

Comment: Just tried and got the same error unfortunately. Thanks, Dev.

Comment: where is `variableName` parametr in your query?? \I cant find one and yet you added a parameter ??

Comment: do-while can throw error if dataReader is empty

Answer (score 2):

In this line

```
  Dashboard_Client.ComboBox_PanelChoice.Items.Add(dataReader("PanelIP"))
```

you are trying to read a field named `PanelIP`, but your query doesn't retrieve it.
This causes the `IndexOutOfRangeException`, because, internally, the reader tries to convert that name (PanelIP) to a position in the list of fields retrieved and when the name doesn't exist then the position is assumed to be -1. Of course -1 is an invalid index in the list of fields retrieved

Said that, let's take a look at your query and how to fix it.

I hope for you that the TableName variable is under your strict control because a user could pass anything in that variable and this could lead to a dangerous situations called Sql Injection

The things to fix are the missing field and change every string concatenation of currentClientID to an appropriate parameter

```
Dim sqlcommand = "SELECT " & TableName & ".[PanelName] " & _ 
                             TableName & ".[PanelID] " & _
                 " FROM  " & TableName & _ 
                 " WHERE (" & TableName & ".[Owner])=@ownerID) " & _
                 " OR    (" & TableName & ".[Admin1])=@clientID1) " & _
                 " OR    (" & TableName & ".[Admin2])=@clientID2) " & _   
                 " OR    (" & TableName & ".[Admin3])=@clientID3) " & _ 
                 " OR    (" & TableName & ".[Admin4])=@clientID4)"

Try
    Using dbConnection As New OleDbConnection(.....)
    Using getSomeData As New OleDbCommand(sqlcommand, dbConnection)
        dbConnection.Open()
        With getSomeData
            ' In oledb you need to add a parameter for every placeholder
            ' because the parameters are not recognized by name but by position
            .Parameters.Add("@ownerID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = currentClientID
            .Parameters.Add("@clientID1", OleDbType.Integer).Value = currentClientID
            .Parameters.Add("@clientID2", OleDbType.Integer).Value = currentClientID
            .Parameters.Add("@clientID3", OleDbType.Integer).Value = currentClientID
            .Parameters.Add("@clientID4", OleDbType.Integer).Value = currentClientID
        End With
        Using dataReader As OleDbDataReader = getSomeData.ExecuteReader
            Do While dataReader.Read
                Dashboard_Client.ComboBox_PanelChoice.Items.Add(dataReader("PanelIP"))
            Loop
        End Using
    End Using
    End Using

    PopCallStack()
Catch ex As Exception
    GlobalErrHandler()
End Try
```

Sadly there is no way to parameterize also the TableName because parameters can be used only for values not for fields or table names

Answer (score 1):

There is no `variableName` parameter in your query ad you are trying to add the value of one .This causes the `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

You mus include the parameter or just remove

```
.Parameters.AddWithValue("@variableName", "variableValue")
```

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't cause the error mentioned by the OP. It is simply ignored. However, I agree that it has no place in the context of the question